# align rows by specific values EXCEL VBA

Tags: excel, vba, alignment, cell, rows

I have a quite large database (about 1500 -2000 records) and I want to align the cells shown on the picture with red to the rows with green. The offsets and records are random, and that's the biggest problem. The values in "B" column are key values after alignment I want to delete empty rows, but I have a method for this, so that's not problem, just the alignment...

Thank you for the help!

[image]

This is how it should look like:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUuvg.png)

Tis is my code, but this is rubbish:

```
Sub xar()
    lastrown = Munka3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row

    For er = 1 To lastrown
        For mer = 1 To lastrown
            If Left(Sheets("EREDMENY").Cells(er, 2).Value, 1) <> "" Then
                If Left(Sheets("EREDMENY").Cells(mer, 1).Value, 1) <> "" Then
                    Sheets("EREDMENY").Cells(er, 1).Value = _
                                         Sheets("EREDMENY").Cells(mer, 1).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next mer
    Next er
End Sub
```

Comment: As you mentioned database, how are you getting the values from database to your sheet?

Comment: in this case the database is sophisticated :) ... i created a script, that imports data from txt files to xls. the txt files contains the aerial and prorietory data of cadastral areas, what an another sript collates to this structure.

Comment: Could you show what the output would look like? Currently your picture shows 4 cells becoming 1 cell.

Comment: I would suggest that you format the data when you read it from the text files. It seems a long way around to import the data to your sheet and then format it

Comment: i added a picture how thw output should look like